# How do the ISponsor and ILease interfaces work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting, object-lifetime

I've created a object that inherits from `MarshalByRefObject` and `ISponsor`. In my implementation of `ISponsor` I just return a timespan to indicate how long I want the object renewed for.

When I call `InitializeLifetimeService()` to get an `ILease` reference to be passed into my `ISponsor` object it never appears to be used [from examples I've seen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.lifetime.isponsor.aspx).

`ISponsor` just seems to return a TimeSpan without actually using the `ILease` reference. But I'm sure there is more going on here since remoting is involved.

How do `ISponsor` and `ILease` work, specifically in terms of object lifetime renewal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In parent AppDomain you obtain ILease object by either `InitializeLifetimeService` or `GetLifetimeService` call with proxy instance of object in the new AppDomain. You never need to implement `ILease` yourself (outside of testing your `ISponsor` implementation).

Than you register your custom Sponsor object which implements `ISponsor` with `ILease.Register` call and configure `ILease` object with timeouts.

When your Sponsor object get called with `Renewal` you can say how long to keep the object alive and also may adjust/display properties of passed in `ILease` instance.

Answer (score 5):

In a client app where you want to extend the lease of a remote object you would typically obtain an ILease interface for the object by calling

```
ILease lease = (ILease)RemotingServices.GetLifetimeService( remoteObject );
```

and then pass it your custom sponsor object

```
lease.Register( customSponsor );
```

where your custom sponsor class will look something like this:

```
private class CustomSponsor : MarshalByRefObject, ISponsor
{
    public TimeSpan Renewal(ILease lease)
    {
        Debug.Assert(lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Active);
        //Renew lease by 5 minutes

        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    }
}
```

For more information check out this helpful MSDN article on leasing and sponsorship.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300474.aspx

The link no longer works - it was in the December 2003 issue though which can be downloaded in CHM format from the same page.

A wayback machine link is here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080906214332/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300474.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the sample code.  The link to the MSDN article is bad, it redirects to the MSDN home page (they must have removed the article).

Comment: @DSO Thanks for pointing that out. It was in the December 2003 issue of MSDN magazine.  I've added a wayback machine link.